# Comments / answers posted last year

Tags: discussion, feature-request, timestamps

I can see that comments / answers / posts posted last year (2015) but less than 365 days ago are formatted like dd:MM (as they were posted in current year) , and if they are posted more than 365 ago their format is dd:MM:yy .

[image]

Shouldn't all the activities from past year show the year (2015)?

Comment: It is a feature: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/add-year-to-question-and-answer-dates/1307#comment8301_2470 and on MSE it was requested before: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226428/show-the-whole-date-even-for-posts-from-the-current-year