# Append year to answer date for answers posted in the current calendar year?

Tags: feature-request

I find it difficult to find the most recent answers to Stack Overflow questions when there are a lot of answers. Sorting can only be done by "active", "oldest", and "votes". To find recent answers sometimes I *command-f* and search for the year e.g: command-f -> '15 to quickly find answers posted in that year (2015). However, this method doesn't work for the current year since years are not a part of the answer date. Ex:

Answer 1: **answered Jan 26 '15 at 12:43** <-- findable via *command-f*: '15

Answer 2: **answered May 18 at 3:33** <-- not findable via *command-f*: '16

Therefore, in lieu of there being no sorting by "newest" or "most recent", wouldn't it be helpful to append the year to answers provided in the current calendar year? Then there wouldn't have to be a wild goose chase of scrolling through answers and reading dates to find ones without the year.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324073/2675154

Comment: It seems that the information is there but only through tool-tips which doesn't make it any easier or efficient to find.

Comment: Why does sorting by 'active' not give you the result you're looking for? The only version of an answer that's visible on the page is the latest version, so an answer from 2015 that was edited in 2016 is, essentially, from 2016.